# Security warning in Win7 from the Links directory

Tags: windows-7, security, shortcuts

Every shortcut placed to the Links bar (C:\Users\user_name\Favorites\Links) shows this security warning:

Open File - Security Warning  Name ... Type: Shortcut ... files from Internet etc.

I can place to this directory shortcut to any program, to IE, Windows Explorer etc. - this security warning is always shown, when the shortcut is executed. How to get rid of this?

OS: Windows 7 Professional Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first we have "turning off protected mode for the whole zone"

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/63141-internet-explorer-protected-mode-turn-off.html

^ Overkill, which just leaves , disconnecting that folder from a zone in the registry, so you can leave the rest protected normally but exclude that folder?  Or, changing the security level for that folder?

http://forums.techarena.in/vista-help/655333.htm

Disclaimer here: about disabling the things that warn users about potential threats, and allow crud from the web to takeover.

Comment: Thanks! There are two working solutions in the second link, I used more secure: Run cmd as adminintrator, execute: 1. cd %userprofile%\favorites 2. icacls links /setintegritylevel (CI)low

Comment: @Psycogeek: This is an old post, but please consider adding the essential information from the links so it isn't a link-only answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The best working solution can be found [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-start-menu-shortcuts-open-file-security-warning-windows-7-vista):

1. Run cmd.exe as Administrator.
2. Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   ```
   ICACLS "C:\Users\user_name\Favorites\Links" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)M
   ```